# How to sign on ethereum a pdf like on this video?

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, react

How to sign on ethereum a pdf like on this video?

I'm asking specifically about what happens at 00:40 where you have a user
uploading the file and then it get stored and cryptographic signature is receive,
how to create that functionality?
https://vimeo.com/239155784

Answer (score 1):

You want to include the hash of the files contents in your signed message to the blockhain

eg, on OSX terminal

```
$ md5 fileToNotarize.doc
MD5 (fileToNotarize.doc) = e789c8f38a10b495614ae07665c8db79
```

Then include the file hash with a transaction message to the blockchain

You also might try running through this tutorial on [how to create a notary on the Ethereum blockchain](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-certificates-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-part-1-45564fd29595)

Also worth checking out [Open Timestamps](https://openTimestamps.org)

Comment: Could you refer me to some tutorials/videos? I finish a few ethereum coding courses but still don’t know how to do that in practice

Comment: See edited answer

Comment: In that video cryptographic signature is created automatically, user who uploads the file doesn't need to send the hash of the files contents, how to implement that kind of feature?